# Get full vanify url with subdomains in PHP

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

My current URL looks like this : 'http://subdomain.domain.com/vanity/url'

When I try to use PHP to get this URL:

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

The var `$url` holds this:

```
 'http://domain.com/index.php?var1=vanity&var2=url';
```

**I want to get the actual URL that is in the address bar. Is this possible?**

Comment: Odd, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` should hold the original, un-rewritten URL.  `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` would hold the path to the current script, regardless of rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing should work - the `REQUEST_URI` key should hold the un-rewritten URI. I guess what you are experiencing is a bug or bizarre misconfiguration in the Apache build you are working with.

Your best bet would be to `print_r($_SERVER)` and see if any of the keys in there hold what you are after - I have just done it on a heavily rewritten site I maintain and the following keys all contained the information you are after, either in part or as a whole:

---

`SCRIPT_URL` - has what `REQUEST_URI` should contain

`SCRIPT_URI` - has the entire URL including http://domain/

`SCRIPT_NAME` - has what `REQUEST_URI` should contain

`PHP_SELF` - has what `REQUEST_URI` should contain

---

Some of these seem odd to me that they should contain this (particularly `PHP_SELF`) but I think this is yet another good reason to not use mod_rewrite unless you absolutely have to...